# Jama How to Shuffle Matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, jama

I am using Jama for my Matrix manipulations at Java. However I could not see an adequate documentation for it.

How can I shuffle a matrix at Jama?

Also is there something like:

```
Matrix(:,end)
```

to get only last column as like at Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (well, at least the documentation of the classes) is [here](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/): http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/

The `Matrix` class has a method `getMatrix()` to extract sub-matrices:

```
/** Get a submatrix.
   @param r    Array of row indices.
   @param c    Array of column indices.
   @return     A(r(:),c(:))
   @exception  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Submatrix indices
   */

   public Matrix getMatrix (int[] r, int[] c) {
      Matrix X = new Matrix(r.length,c.length);
      double[][] B = X.getArray();
      try {
         for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
               B[i][j] = A[r[i]][c[j]];
            }
         }
      } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Submatrix indices");
      }
      return X;
   }
```

`Jama` is not overly complicated. It should be very easy to add a `getColumn()` method to `Matrix.java`.